# dudas con documentación de Angular 5

Tags: angular5

Mi duda es exactamente en [este articulo](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data), ahí aparece que se debe crear un config.json en la carpeta assetsy luego llamarlo en el service de esta forma:

assets/config.json

```
{
 "heroesUrl": "api/heroes",
  "textfile": "assets/textfile.txt"
}
```

app/config/config.service.ts

```
configUrl = 'assets/config.json';

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
```

sin embargo al hacer esto en mi código no  obtengo la url completa, sino que obtengo `assets/config.json`.
La pregunta es ¿cómo debería hacer para obtener la url de manera correcta?

Más abajo dice que debo poner en el component esto:

app/config/config.component.ts

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe(data => this.config = {
        heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
        textfile:  data['textfile']
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, no pone que se *deba* crear. Ese artículo es un ejemplo de cómo leer datos en formato JSON que están en un fichero del servidor. *Hipotéticamente* podrías necesitar tener un fichero de configuración que tu aplicación usaría para obtener datos necesarios, como una lista de URLs.

Aclarado ésto, si haces una llamada GET (o POST, pero usaré GET en esta explicación) con esas URLs tienes que entender lo siguiente:

Imaginemos que tu aplicación hecha con Angular se ha cargado al acceder a la dirección siguiente:

```
www.midominio.com/app/
```

Por tanto, esa dirección es la URL base. De hecho, lo normal es que definas esa URL en el fichero index.html de este modo:

```
<base href="https://www.midominio.com/app/" />
```

Por defecto, Angular te crea esa etiqueta así:

```
<base href="/" />
```

¿Qué hace esta etiqueta? Pues si visitamos la documentación de la web [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/base), leemos que:

> El elemento HTML `<base>` especifica la dirección URL base que se
>   utilizará para todas las direcciones URL relativas contenidas dentro
>   de un documento. Sólo puede haber un elemento `<base>` en un documento.

Por tanto, si haces una llamada usando el siguiente código:

```
configUrl = 'assets/config.json';
...
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl); 
}
```

El navegador asumirá que la dirección es relativa a la dirección actual y, por tanto, usará la URL base para concatenar, obteniendo

```
https://www.midominio.com/app/assets/config.json
```

Comment: tengo un servicio montado con nodemon, y lo llamo http://localhost:300/api/ ¿en este caso cómo lo llamaría?

Comment: ¿Cargas tu aplicación desde un lugar distinto?

Comment: en este momento esta en mi misma maquina, sin  embargo más adelante pienso montarlo en otra maquina

Comment: Con *lugar* estaba pensando servidor o puerto... lo normal es tener un proxy inverso para que todo pase por el mismo sitio. Si tu API REST está en otro servidor, deberías usar la URL absoluta en cada llamada.

Comment: es decir, sería bueno tener un archivo llamado config.ts y crear la clase que tenga la dirección y cada que lo llame llamar esa dirección?

Comment: Si usas angular CLI en tu proyecto, seguramente tengas ya un archivo environment.ts y environment.prod.ts... úsalo para guardar esas variables. El primero es para desarrollo y el segundo para producción